# templateUrl does not work sometimes in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Sometimes templateUrl does not work

```
.when(url('/:type/:id/xyz'), {
      templateUrl: template('xyz.html'),
      controller: 'xyz',
      title: 'xyz'
    })
```

my code is this api is calling but sometimes xyz.html does not working.

can you please suggest thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because, it doesn't need the `template(..)` format.
The correct format is

```
templateUrl: 'filename.html'
```

Extract from the official documentation

> templateUrl – {string=|function()=} – path or function that returns a
>   path to an html template that should be used by ngView.
>
> If templateUrl is a function, it will be called with the following
>   parameters:
>
> {Array.} - route parameters extracted from the current
>   $location.path() by applying the current route